# How to validate MySQL alter, create queries..?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, alter

I have some situation where code generates SQL queries based on current structure  of table and new version of table structure. How can I check those queries generated by the class are valid because sometime the class causes the errors building alter, drop column queries specially when it is related to primary key, auto number togather.

so I want to put something in place so I can see if the generated queries have any errors or not, before executing them. I can't do it in transactions because its alterations on table. I am using ADOdB for PHP

Comment: I think you'd better log each specific error you get and solve the problem in the part that generates the query. Much easier to rewrite that part than to write a query parser yourself.

Comment: query parsing is not a simple job. So I agree with @GolezTrol Try solving your problem by handling your code.

Comment: Does anyone know any tool that can compare two table structure and generate alter,drop,add queries accordingly for 2nd table, currently I am using modified version of [link](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/23284.html) , but I need something better